# Dynamic SQL Query is not returning data into SQL sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have Dynamic SQL Query like below

Dynamic SQL Query:

```
Declare @Currentmonth4date varchar(8)= convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 3),112)
Declare @SQL varchar(max)= 'dbo.Exclusion_Process_Tab1_' + '20181204'

Declare @Select varchar(400) = 'Select * from ' + @SQL

exec (@Select)
```

I have tried to execute this code from excel'2010 through microsoft query source.

after clicking on return data to option form query window,it is not returning the data into excel sheet.

Please help

Comment: Create an SP, put the code inside it and call the SP from Excel. And you don't use your variable @Currentmonth4date

Comment: i don't have permissions to create sp , could you please suggest if is there any other approach that you know

Comment: I think there is an erratum in the code provided, I guess you wanted to say in line 2 "Declare @SQL varchar(max)= 'dbo.Exclusion_Process_Tab1_' + @Currentmonth4date"

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to test your dynamic sql

It is returning `Select * from dbo.Exclusion_Process_Tab1_20181204`

try this

```
Declare @Currentmonth4date varchar(8)= convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 3),112)
Declare @SQL varchar(max)= 'dbo.Exclusion_Process_Tab1_'+ @Currentmonth4date

Declare @Select varchar(400) = 'Select * from '+@SQL

PRINT(@SELECT)

--exec (@Select)
```

This one is returning

```
Select * from dbo.Exclusion_Process_Tab1_20190104
```

After testing comment print and uncomment exec

Before executing your dynamic queries test them with print and see what do they return.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic SQL, what's the point?

You just doing something like:

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM dbo.Exclusion_Process_Tab1_20181204')
```

Why not just:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Exclusion_Process_Tab1_20181204
```

And omit all unnecessary variables.